# Will SE block me if my questions are consistently marked as off-topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions

What will happen to my account if I post off-topic posts quite frequently, albeit not intentionally?

Comment: The full documentation (about what happens if the relevant mechanisms do kick in) is on [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/) at [meta.se]. It seems that you're some way away from this happening, but it's worth a read just to understand the playing field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SE will block your account from posting new questions if your existing questions are judged to be low quality, but the exact criteria they use have never been disclosed - presumably to stop people from gaming the system.

I have read your existing questions, and you are obviously enthusiastic about physics. Can I suggest you ask in the [Physics Stack Exchange chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) before posting a question if you are concerned it might be closed. You can ask anything about physics there without fear of your account being blocked.

Comment: @SrijanSuryansh we are a friendly bunch in the chat room and several experienced physicists hang out there. We even have a string theorist there :-) It can be better than the main site for answering questinos when you're not exactly sure what you want to ask, because the chat room allows for extended discussions.

Comment: I know i'm violating SE regulation but still once again thanks.

Comment: @SrijanSuryansh It's not about anybody "violating regulations". We in the Physics site have set up some guidelines about what is and is not on-topic, to help keep the content quality high, and the SE software has some restrictions built-in to prevent (real) abuse, but the core is still that we're here to help people. For some things (like the speculative questions you've had closed), then as John points out the best approach is to bash them out in chat to make sure they're on-topic for the main site. Welcome, and looking forward to your future contributions!

Comment: @EmilioPisanty oh sorry you misinterpreted me i just wanted say JohnRennie thanks
but SE says I should not type comments for saying thanks or +1 etc

Comment: @SrijanSuryansh No worries. There's nothing wrong with writing comments to say thanks -- the rules just say that those comments may be deleted in the interest of keeping the site clean (i.e. as a repository for information instead of an archive of conversations from years ago). Moreover, those rules are a bit relaxed here on Meta ;-).

Comment: Who is the string theorist ? Just wondering.

Comment: Oh yeah I would like to know too